# How do you comment out all or part of a Lisp s-exp using Paredit?

Tags: emacs, lisp, paredit

When editing Lisp code, occasionally it's useful to entirely comment out a top-level definition, like this:

```
;(defun some-fn-which-is-broken (x)
;  ...)
```

... or comment out only part of an s-expression, like this:

```
(foo x
;    y
     z)
```

... and then recompile the file and test something in the REPL, etc.

With paredit-mode enabled, this doesn't work. Here's what happens, if the point is right before the first paren below:

```
(defun some-fn (x)
  ...)
```

and you type a semicolon, what is entered is a semicolon and a newline:

```
;
(defun some-fn (x)
  ...)
```

Same with commenting out part of the s-expression:

```
(foo x
;    
     y
     z)
```

I think that if the definition is all on one line, this works:

```
;(defparameter *foo* 10)
```

... but otherwise I can't find out how to do this. Paredit is great, I would really like to keep using it. Are there any Lispers who know a way around this, or Emacs-wizards who can whip up a bit of Emacs Lisp to bind to something like `paredit-comment-out-s-expr`?

If there is a more Lispy or Emacsy way of accomplishing essentially the same thing, commenting out parts of source to recompile, please, don't hesitate to suggest them!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Position the point on the first character of the whole sexp, mark the whole sexp with <kbd>C-M-space</kbd>, and issue <kbd>M-;</kbd> to do the commenting. If it is necessary to do so, your source code will also be re-formatted so that only the sexp you marked, and nothing that was also on the same line, is in a comment.

You can very easily make a simple command or even a macro to do that:

```
(defun comment-sexp ()
  "Comment out the sexp at point."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-sexp)
    (paredit-comment-dwim)))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @spacemanaki Also, pressing C-M-SPC multiple times select multiple s-expressions, and pressing C-M-u multiple times let you to get to the position you want before pressing C-M-SPC

Answer (score 13):

Just a side note:

The `#+` and `#-` reader macros are pretty nice for commenting out sexps. They allow ignoring the following sexp, if the given symbol isn't/is found in `*FEATURES*`. Just pick a symbol not in `*FEATURES*`, and use it with `#+` like this:

```
#+nil
(defun foo ()
  ...)
```

Now, the function definition will be ignored (unless `NIL` is in `*FEATURES*`, which is not very likely).

Comment: If you want to be super-safe, you can use (OR) instead of NIL.

Answer (score 4):

As a stopgap measure, you can use <kbd>C-q</kbd> (`quoted-insert`) to insert an arbitrary character without triggering any mode-related magic.  For example, in java-mode, typing parentheses reindents the current line, which is not always what I want; in such cases, I'll insert a parenthesis with <kbd>C-q</kbd> to preserve my indentation.  (Or more often, I'll type a parenthesis, observe the indentation change, curse, undo, and re-enter with <kbd>C-q</kbd>.)

For commenting in general, it would probably be easier to use <kbd>M-;</kbd> (`comment-dwim`) rather than typing the semicolons manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `C-M-SPC M-;` to mark the S-expression (`C-M-SPC` for `mark-sexp`) and then comment it (`M-;` for `comment-dwim`).

In paredit 23, just typing `;` won't push anything it doesn't have to off the line.  So it will do the right thing for your second example.  And if you wanted to comment out `z` instead of `y` it would push only the closing delimiter to another line.