# Emacs Paredit: how to delete comment semicolons

Tags: emacs, comments

Based on [How do you comment out all or part of a Lisp s-exp using Paredit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288339/how-do-you-comment-out-all-or-part-of-a-lisp-s-exp-using-paredit) I did `C-M-space` then `M-;` and got, as expected, a commented-out S-exp:

```
;; (when window-system
;;     (sr-speedbar-open))
```

Now how do I delete those semicolons? When I try the obvious (backspace or delete), only one semicolon disappears.  I also can't just undo, since I've done other stuff between adding the semicolons and wanting to delete them.  I could also turn off paredit for this task, but I'm certain there's a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is re-select the region and then do `M-;` again, which will un-comment the given region if it's already commented. You could also try [this function that I've put together](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/30278/10761) which deletes backwards on a given line, while still preserving delimiters (it's basically a backwards `paredit-kill`). You'd just navigate to the spot after the comment semicolons and then invoke `paredit-backward-delete-line`, preferably with whatever key binding that you bound it to (which was `<C-backspace>` in my above answer).